# Strange result in modulo calculation

Tags: javascript, math

```
-224 / -37.333333333333336 = 6
-224 % -37.333333333333336 = -37.33333333333332
(-224 / -37.333333333333336) % 1 = 0
```

Why doesn't `%` return `0` if the first result is `6`?

And why isn't the result a `float` in the third calculation?

Comment: Well the last one makes sense; dividing by 1 leaves a remainder of zero in all cases. It's the second one that's hurting my head.

Comment: @Pointy It's a rounding issue, if you remove some threes at the end, you get a value close to zero.

Comment: @phant0m this is not just a simple question about how floating-point math works. Can you explain the second operation in the OP?

Comment: @Pointy, `-224 / -37.333333333333337` is also `6`, and `-224 / -37.333333333333338` too. It's looks like a precision issue, I believe phant0m is right.

Comment: @Somebody the result in the third calculation **is** a float; **all** numbers are floats in JavaScript. The fact that it's not *printed* as a float is just an artifact of the way numbers are turned into strings.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes but that result just seems wildly off. (*edit* ok I think I'm starting to get it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*All* numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floating point numbers. Just because it doesn't display  the number as `0.0` doesn't mean it's not a double.

According to WolframAlpha:

```
-224 / -37.333333333333336 = 5.9999999999999995714285...
```

Due to accuracy limitations / rounding in floating point division, the division results in 6 in JavaScript.

The modulo operation, however, correctly sees that -37.3… doesn't quite fit into -224 six times. That means that the other 99.99…% of -37.33… is a leftover after the division, which corresponds to result of the modulo operation.

Hence, you get *almost*, but not quite, the divisor back.

Comment: I don't understand how we go from numbers close to zero, all the way to -37.

Comment: @Pointy I added a hopefully intuitive (not entirely accurate, maths wise) explanation  for why that happens.

Comment: Ah OK, I guess that makes sense.

Comment: @Pointy I have corrected my post after checking the exact results with WolframAlpha.

Comment: Yes, I think I just had not had quite enough coffee before :)  Thanks for doing the research.